# Python: Elegant way to replace a given dictionary by child key somewhere in a tree?

Tags: python, oop, recursion

Is there some kind of enumeration library or method I should use or should I write from scratch with recursion?

I'm parsing a JSON tree into an object tree as it happens, and I'd like to replace some nodes with other kinds of objects.

E.g:

```
db = {'bigBang' :
          {'stars':
               {'planets': {}, 'is_list':true
               }
           }
     }
db.deepReplace( 'is_list', ['earth', 'mars'] )
>> db is now: 
>> {'bigBang' :
>>        {'stars':
>>             {'planets':
>>                 {
>>                     ['earth', 'mars']
>>                 }
>>             }
>>         }
>> }
```

Comment: Anything exceptionally clever is going to run the risk of replacing the wrong value if your keys are not globally unique.  (e.g., what happens when someone tries to enter a planet named `stars`, and does `db.deepReplace('stars', {'size' : 1000000, 'transit' : 47})`?)

Comment: I had a bad example, I just changed it. I want to replace a given class of JSON objects to smart Python objects with the same data but more than regular dict functions :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't supply the proper path (e.g. `bigBang.stars.planets`)?  It just seems somewhat crazy to try to do this without context.

Comment: it's automated so there is no human to give a path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there's only one node to replace:

```
def deepReplace(d, key, value):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if key in d:
            d[key] = value
            return True
        else:
            for k,v in d.iteritems():
                if deepReplace(v, key, value):
                    return True
    return False
```

Otherwise:

```
def deepReplace(d, key, value):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if key in d:
            d[key] = value
        else:
            for k,v in d.iteritems():
                deepReplace(v, key, value):
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish; I guess you want `deepReplace` to replace any node named "planets" with a map containing "earth" and "mars"?

It's pretty easy to write that function, especially if you know the tree will contain `dict`s.  If not, you need to test the type (or catch the errors) when you try and recurse.

```
def deep_replace(d, key, replacement):
    for k, value in d.items():
        if k == key:
            d[k] = replacement
        else:
            deep_replace(value, key, replacement)
```